# adding extra lines after each line in a file

Tags: python, sed, awk

adding extra lines after each line in a file

I need help for the following task for around 1000 lines file.

INPUT

```
    ./create.pl     1eaj.out
    ./create.pl     1ezg.out
    ./create.pl     1f41.out
    ...
```

OUTPUT

```
    ./create.pl     1eaj.out
    mv complex.* 1eaj
    ./create.pl     1ezg.out
    mv complex.* 1ezg
    ./create.pl     1f41.out
    mv complex.* 1f41
    ...
```

I know following command can add the new line and first part which makes the output like below.

```
    awk ' {print;} NR % 1 == 0 { print "mv complex.*  "; }'

    ./create.pl     1eaj.out
    mv complex.* 
    ./create.pl     1ezg.out
    mv complex.* 
    ./create.pl     1f41.out
    mv complex.* 
    ...
```

How to do the rest?
Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: You could consider writing a loop to achieve what you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My attempt:

```
sed -n 's/^\(\.\/create\.pl\)\s*\(.*\)\.out$/\1 \2.out\nmv complex.* \2/p' s.txt
```

or using `&&` between `./create.pl` and `mv` (since mv is likely needed only when  `./create.pl` is correctly executed):

```
sed -n 's/^\(\.\/create\.pl\)\s*\(.*\)\.out$/\1 \2.out \&\& mv complex.* \2/p' s.txt
```

which gives:

```
./create.pl 1eaj.out && mv complex.* 1eaj
./create.pl 1ezg.out && mv complex.* 1ezg
./create.pl 1f41.out && mv complex.* 1f41
```

Answer (score 3):

You were nearly there:

```
$ awk '{print $1, $2, "\nmv complex.*", $2}' file
./create.pl 1eaj.out 
mv complex.* 1eaj.out
./create.pl 1ezg.out 
mv complex.* 1ezg.out
./create.pl 1f41.out 
mv complex.* 1f41.out
```

Answer (score 2):

Use whitespace or dots as the delimiter to extract the word you need:

```
awk -F '[[:blank:].]+' '{print; print "mv complex.*", $4}' filename
```